# What's the difference between (typeof variable === "function") and jQuery.isFunction()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, typeof

I have always used `(typeof variable === "function")` and I stumbled across `jQuery.isFunction()` and I was wondering:

1. What is the difference between the typeof method and jQuery's method? And not only what the difference is, but
2. When is it appropriate to use the typeof method and when is it appropriate to use jQuery's method?

Comment: This comment can be helpful http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isFunction/#comment-128339529

Comment: Yes that is a good comment. :)

Comment: what comment was that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is *almost* no difference, other than that using jQuery is slightly slower. See the source code:

```
isFunction: function( obj ) {
    return jQuery.type(obj) === "function";
},
```

which calls a function which calls another function to determine the *exact* same thing as what you showed :P

There is literally no advantage to jQuery in this case [or for that manner, 90% of the use-cases of the library]. Look into [Vanilla-JS](http://vanilla-js.com/) and check out some of its features :P

TLDR: Don't use jQuery for this...or anything.

#### UPDATE

Here's a benchmark showing you that Vanilla JS is roughly 93% faster than jQuery: http://jsperf.com/jquery-isfunction-vs-vanilla-is-function.

Comment: *jQuery is slightly slower* ^_^

Comment: In their defense, there had been a Chrome bug where `typeof` on a regex would return `"function"`, but with Chrome's automatic update install, that bug should be long gone.

Comment: @user1600680 `$.isFunction` existed long before that bug and exists long after it, though :P

Comment: jQuery does NOT do the same thing as the OP's question.  jQuery ends up examining `Object.prototype.toString.call()` and looking for `[object Function]` which is not the same as `typeof fn === "function"`.

Comment: Fair enough, I realized that after posting and weaving through the complete mess that is its codebase. It accomplishes the same end in all but a few rare edge cases AFAIK.

Comment: While checking whether a function was defined with typeof myFunction  Chrome and Firefox was returning `function` whereas IE8 returned `object`. I guess `jQuery.isFunction` prevents that?

Answer (score 4):

<strike>There's no difference. jQuery uses the same concept:</strike>

```
// ...
isFunction: function( obj ) {
    return jQuery.type(obj) === "function";
}
```

**Update:**

After digging in deeper I found that jQuery's `isFunction` method is comparing the `toString` method of the `Object.prototype` chain on `function() {}`, to the string `[object Function]`. This is the how it differs from your former example and the reason for it being slower than `typeof`.

Comment: @JohnB - So you're saying that sometimes jQuery.isFunction() doesn't identify functions as functions as well?

Comment: @JohnB - Well if they both fail sometimes, I might as well stick with `typeof variable === "function"` :)

Comment: Please forget my comments (those which I have deleted). They were nonsense. Honestly, I do not know whether there are functions that are not identified as functions by jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

The jQuery source code for isFunction is

```
isFunction: function( obj ) {
    return jQuery.type(obj) === "function";
},

type: function( obj ) {
return obj == null ?
   String( obj ) :
   class2type[ core_toString.call(obj) ] || "object";
},

//...

jQuery.each("Boolean Number String Function Array Date RegExp Object".split(" "),
   function(i, name) {
      class2type[ "[object " + name + "]" ] = name.toLowerCase();
});

core_toString = Object.prototype.toString,
```

hence `jQuery.isFunction` returns true if and only if calling `Object.prototype.toString.call` on its argument returns `[object Function]`.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question for what circumstances this would generate a different result than `typeof fn === "function"`.  I know the jQuery way works better for arrays, but why do it that way for a function if you don't already have that library around?

Comment: @Vitim.us - me too, but that isn't in this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Usually you can test whether JS object is function by using this test:

```
(typeof fn === 'function')
```

However, this doesn't always work (IE8):

```
typeof alert => 'object'
typeof document.createElement('input').getAttribute => 'object'
```

Before jQuery 1.4 internally they used the same check, but now they've fixed it. So to be sure that passed object is a function which can be called, just use $.isFunction method:

```
$.isFunction(function() {}) => true
$.isFunction(alert) => true
$.isFunction(document.createElement('input').getAttribute) => true
```

Copied from this blog: http://nuald.blogspot.co.uk/2012/07/why-jqueryisfunction.html

Comment: The blog is wrong. As of 1.3, $.isFunction(alert) returns false in IE<9 while it returns true in 1.2.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that JQuery calls something equivalent to the following and checks for the "Function" string token:

```
var toString = Object.prototype.toString;
var func = function(){};

console.log(toString.call(func)); // "returns [object Function]"
```

Whereas typof, just returns "function":

```
var fType = typeof func; 

console.log(fType); // returns "function"
```

[Here's an example.](http://jsfiddle.net/JzPvw/)