# Difference between JQuery.type and typeof, which is faster

Tags: jquery

I have a method called processData, in which i have used the below code to check the type of the variable

```
typeof series.dataSource.xName == "string"

jQuery.type(series.dataSource.xName)=="string"
```

i what to know which is faster, and will take less time to execute, overall "type" need 55ms to execute, i need to optimize it

Thanks in advance

Comment: Raw javascript is always faster than jQuery.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12206083/whats-the-difference-between-typeof-variable-function-and-jquery-isfunc

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but if i have the variable a= new Date(2000, 7,7) which contain the date has above and "typeof a" returns "object", but its date, how can i check?

Answer (score 3):

This is your answer [See](http://jsperf.com/jquery-type-vs-native-typeof/2) in Detail....

Comment: Your link is no longer available

Answer (score 2):

It's 10x-20x times faster when using vanilla JS than jQuery. However there are a few types where jQuery will give more information about the value. So here are the differences:

```
╔══════════════════════════════════════════════╦════════════════════════════════════════╗
║                   jQuery                     ║                 Vanilla                ║
╠══════════════════════════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ jQuery.type(null) === 'null'                 ║ typeof null === 'object'               ║
║                                              ║                                        ║
║ jQuery.type(new Boolean()) === 'boolean'     ║ typeof new Boolean() === 'object'      ║
║ jQuery.type(Boolean()) === 'boolean'         ║ typeof Boolean() === 'object'          ║
║ jQuery.type(Object(Boolean())) === 'boolean' ║ typeof Object(Boolean()) === 'object'  ║
║                                                                                       ║
║ Same applies to all other Constructors i.e. same result with/without new/Object()     ║
║                                                                                       ║
║ jQuery.type(new Number(42)) === 'number'     ║ typeof new Number(42) === 'object'     ║
║ jQuery.type(new String('test')) === 'string' ║ typeof new String('test') === 'object' ║
║ jQuery.type(new Date()) === 'date'           ║ typeof new Date() === 'object'         ║
║ jQuery.type(new Array()) === 'array'         ║ typeof new Array() === 'object'        ║
║ jQuery.type(new RegExp()) === 'regexp'       ║ typeof new RegExp() === 'object'       ║
║ jQuery.type(new Error()) === 'error'         ║ typeof new Error() === 'object'        ║
║                                              ║                                        ║
║ jQuery.type([]) === 'array'                  ║ typeof [] === 'object'                 ║
║ jQuery.type(/test/) === 'regexp'             ║ typeof /test/ === 'object'             ║
║                                              ║                                        ║
║ jQuery.type(Symbol()) === 'symbol'           ║ typeof Symbol() === 'symbol' (same)    ║
║ jQuery.type(Object(Symbol())) === 'symbol'   ║ typeof Object(Symbol()) === 'object'   ║
╚══════════════════════════════════════════════╩════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

However I suggest to go with dedicated methods in Lodash. E.g.  `_.isUndefined`, `_.isString`, `_.isNull`, `_.isDate`, `_.isError`, `_.isRegExp`, `_.isSymbol`, etc.

And even more powerful:
`_.isNil`, `_.isNaN`, `_.isEmpty`, `_.isArrayLike`, `_.isObjectLike`, `_.isPlainObject`, `_.isTypedArray`, `_.isSet`, `_.isWeakMap`, etc.