# jQuery.type() is deprecated. When checking if a var is not an object, what should I use instead?

Tags: jquery

[jQuery.type() is deprecated in jQuery 3.3 and above.](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.type/) When refactoring older code that uses this API, what should I use instead of jQuery.type()?

For example, one of the plugins my page relies on uses the $.type() API as illustrated below.

```
if ($.type(button) !== 'object') {
     throw new Error('button with key "' + key + '" must be an object');
}
```

I'd like to replace it with something that isn't deprecated.

Comment: Well, just going off of the variable name, potentially `!button || !button.tagName || button.tagName !== 'BUTTON'`

Comment: https://j11y.io/jquery/#v=1.11.2&fn=jQuery.type  You could also look at the source code and see what they were doing

Answer (score 2):

From your link I clicked on the depreciated version and got here: https://api.jquery.com/category/version/3.3/

That let me click the release notes link: https://blog.jquery.com/2018/01/19/jquery-3-3-0-a-fragrant-bouquet-of-deprecations-and-is-that-a-new-feature/

Where I found the github commits for the change:
https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/3605
https://github.com/jquery/jquery/commit/1ea092a54b00aa4d902f4e22ada3854d195d4a18

They depreciated this because the 'class2type' table didn't handle new data types to the point of being useless. They revert their own internal code to use vanilla js `typeof` - I assume that's the expected change for your code base.

Also, see here: [Difference between JQuery.type and typeof, which is faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19921838/difference-between-jquery-type-and-typeof-which-is-faster)
Namely the second answer for the loss of detail in reading certain types. If that's problematic for you, I guess it's just workarounds like the kind @Taplar suggested / your answer to this question(Edit/Update).

Answer (score 0):

It appears that based on [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8511350/3680712), you can use `typeof yourVariable === 'object' && yourVariable !== null` to determine if a variable is an object (note that you must also check that it is not a null since JS considers nulls to be objects.)

Since we need to throw an error if the `button` variable is NOT an object, we should be able to change the code to use `typeof` like so:

```
if (typeof button !== 'object' || typeof button === null) {
     throw new Error('button with key "' + key + '" must be an object');
}
```

(Note that we have to throw an error if the `button` var is null, because while JavaScript `typeof` considers nulls to be objects, it's not the type of object we're looking for.)

In short, you'll want to replace `jQuery.type()` with a `typeof` comparison.

Comment: You could also shortcircuit to undefined.  `typeof (button || undefined) !== 'object'`